# Absent itemsid Free disk space on /data in API answer

Tags: zabbix

I make get API request for Zabbix 3.2

```
zabbix_get=\
    {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "item.get",
        "params": {
            "output": "extend",
            "hostids": 123,
            "search": {
                "key_": "system"
            },
            "sortfield": "name"
        },
        "auth": authToken.get("result"),
        "id": authToken.get("id")
    }
```

and sent it.

Returned many itemid CPU and others.
I not checked all.
BUT I not found itemid with Free disk space on /data.

How solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for `system` in the key, but [Zabbix item key](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) for diskspace is `vfs.fs.size[]`.

Note that it is not guaranteed that you even have an item, monitoring free space on `/data`.

Comment: {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "item.get",
        "params": {
            "output": "extend",
            "hostids": 123,
            "search": {
                "key_": "vfs.fs.size"
            },
            "sortfield": "name"
        },
        "auth": authToken.get("result"),
        "id": authToken.get("id")
    }